# combine multiple columns in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I am entirely new to Pig. I want to combine multiple columns from two relation A and B using iid field. This seems to be simple, but I cannot figure out how to do it correctly, i've tried join but since there is no column in common it givs nothing.

so here is my data:

```
A
FullName Age CIN

B    
evaluation productivty
```

and I want my output to be like this:

```
FullName Age CIN Evaluation Productivty
```

..       ..  ..     ..         ..

Thanks

Comment: To join these two data sheet at least you need one column to common in these data sheet..

Comment: so there is no other way?

Answer (score 1):

You need a common key to join two tables. If you want to combine two datasets without a key, you can use CROSS. It computes the cross product of both the data sets.

```
A = LOAD 'a.txt' AS (FullName, Age, CIN);
B = LOAD 'b.txt' AS (evaluation, productivity);
C = CROSS A,B;
```

If you want to join line by line and assume that data is in order in both the files, you can use UniqueID as a hack (Pig 0.14 and later only)

```
A = LOAD 'a.txt' AS (FullName, Age, CIN);
B = LOAD 'b.txt' AS (evaluation, productivity);
A1 = FOREACH A GENERATE *, UniqueID(FullName) AS id;
B1 = FOREACH B GENERATE *, UniqueID(evaluation) AS id;
C = JOIN A1 BY id, B1 BY id;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE FullName, Age, CIN, evaluation, productivity;
```

This completely depends on the implementation of UniqueID and might not fetch desired results if logic changes in next versions.

Answer (score 0):

Load the two relations and create a new relation with all the columns.Assuming both files have same number of rows and fields are tab delimited.You can use the right datatype based on your data.

```
A = LOAD 'data1.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') as (FullName:chararray,Age:int,CIN:int);
B = LOAD 'data2.txt' USING PigStorage('\t') as (Evaluation:chararray,Productivity:chararray);
C = FOREACH A GENERATE A.Fullname,A.Age,A.CIN,B.Evaluation,B.Productivity;
DUMP C;
```